# What HTTP Request (GET,POST,PUT,DELETE) does the html-tag <link> trigger?

Tags: html, http

`<a>` triggers a GET-Request for example, but what does `<link>` trigger? `<img>` also triggers a GET-Request

I dont know how to answer this myself and chatgpt says nothing triggers it, but im not content with this answer.

Answer (score 1):

`<link>` associates a URL with the current document and defines its relationship to that URL. There's no implicit HTTP method associated with `<link>` itself.

For example, a [webmention link](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-webmention-20170112/#sender-discovers-receiver-webmention-endpoint) expects [a POST request](https://www.w3.org/TR/2017/REC-webmention-20170112/#sender-notifies-receiver) to be made to it.

The [canonical relation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6596) doesn't specify how the URL should be requested at all, but the implication is that the same request methods for the current URL are supported on the canonical one.